# Java Iterator that return Null

Tags: iterator, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to write a method in java using Iterator, which Iterates through some comments on a sale item and return back a Comment which is most helpful based on the votes for the comment. However, in cases where there are no comments at all, I want the code to return null. But my problem is that the below code is giving me a "no such element exception", how can I fix that?

```
 public Comment findMostHelpfulComment()
{
    Iterator<Comment> it = comments.iterator();
    Comment best = it.next();
    while(it.hasNext()) 
    {
        Comment current = it.next();
        if(current.getVoteCount() > best.getVoteCount()) {
            best = current;
        }

    }
    return best;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Comment findMostHelpfulComment()
{
    if (comments.isEmpty()== true){
        return null;
    }
    else{

    Iterator<Comment> it = comments.iterator();
    Comment best = it.next();
    while(it.hasNext()) 
    {
        Comment current = it.next();
        if(current.getVoteCount() > best.getVoteCount()) {
            best = current;
        }

    }
    return best;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Comment best = it.next();
```

this will give you nosuch element exception if comments are null.
either you need to check for null, or do `it.hasNext()` before `Comment best = it.next()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public Comment findMostHelpfulComment() {
    Iterator < Comment > it = comments.iterator();
    Comment best = new Comment();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Comment current = it.next();
        if (current.getVoteCount() > best.getVoteCount()) {
            best = current;
        }
    }
    return best;
}
```

Please try the above code.
Instead of using `it.next()` at the time of declaring, it is better to declare it with an empty `Comment` object. By doing so, it will skip fetching the data from the `Iterator` without checking.

This will not throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it was bringing compiler error when I run your modified code above, the error being line 3 about Comment best. However, I figured out another way by checking if the comments arraylist is empty first before going to the iterator, i.e. this is now my modified code and is working fine: